# Passing a PHP variable to JavaScript in a Blade template

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

is there any ways that JavaScript can get the variable from the controller in a Laravel Blade template?

Example:
I have the code below:

```php
$langs = Language::all();
return View::make('NAATIMockTest.Admin.Language.index',compact('langs'));
```

Can I get `$langs` and pass it to JavaScript? I already used [PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer). But when I use `JavaScript::put()` for two functions in the controller. It didn't work. Any help?

This is my create function in the controller:

```php
public function create()
{
    $names = $this->initLang();
    Javascript::put([
        'langs' => $names
    ]);
    
    return View::make('NAATIMockTest.Admin.Language.create',compact('names'));
}
```

this is my view:

```html
@extends('AdLayout')
@section('content')
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('langCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.languages = langs;
    });
</script>
    
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="langCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2>Create language</h2>
                </div>
                    
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! Form::open() !!}
                        <p class="text-center">
                            {!! Form::label('Name','Language: ') !!}
                            <input type="text" name="searchLanguage" ng-model="searchLanguage">
                        </p>
    
                        <select name="Name[]" multiple size="10" ng-model="lang" ng-click="show()">
                            <option value="@{{v}}" ng-repeat="(k,v) in languages | filter:searchLanguage">
                                @{{v}}
                            </option>
                        </select><br>
    
                        <div class="text-center">
                            {!! Form::submit('Create',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}&nbsp;
                            {!!   Html::linkAction('NAATIMockTest\LanguageController@index', 'Back', null, array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) !!}
                        </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

my javascript.php in config folder:

```php
<?php
return [
    'bind_js_vars_to_this_view' => 'footer',
    'bind_js_vars_to_this_view' => 'NAATIMockTest.Admin.Language.create',
    'bind_js_vars_to_this_view' => 'NAATIMockTest.Admin.Language.edit',
    
    'js_namespace' => 'window',
];
```

The idea is:
I have a table language in MySQL. I want to show the dropdown list with multiple attributes to choose, and I also want to search with angularjs as well. That's why I want to pass the variable from the controller to JavaScript. Additionally, I have the function inside LanguageController called initLang to check if any language is exist inside the database, it isn't displayed inside the dropdown list in create the view.

Comment: can you also show how you wish to use langs in your javacript code?

Comment: Since you are already using a package, please show us the code that doesn't work. (edit your question)

Comment: Maybe the two functions did render the view or partial,  you have chosen to bind the javascript variables to?

Comment: it only works for edit view, but for a create view i doesn't work at all. i wanna use angularjs to search instead of using laravel

Comment: [Check this](http://heera.it/laravel-pass-user-object-javascript-object).

Comment: Try this - https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer
Is simple way to append PHP variables to Javascript.

Answer (score 128):

One working example for me.

Controller:

```
public function tableView()
{
    $sites = Site::all();
    return view('main.table', compact('sites'));
}
```

View:

```
<script>    
    var sites = {!! json_encode($sites->toArray()) !!};
</script>
```

To prevent malicious / unintended behaviour, you can use `JSON_HEX_TAG` as suggested by Jon in the comment that links to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24970388/2701130)

```
<script>    
    var sites = {!! json_encode($sites->toArray(), JSON_HEX_TAG) !!};
</script>
```

Comment: You may want to add JSON_HEX_TAG to json_encode `{!! json_encode($sites->toArray(), JSON_HEX_TAG) !!};` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855186/most-efficient-way-to-pass-php-variables-to-external-javascript-or-jquery-file

Comment: @ken Oh this actually does work, but there are quotes in the beginning and at the end of the html. How can I get rid of them?

Comment: nvm, I didn't realise that i didnt need the quotes when using `json_encode`

Comment: or just `var sites = @json($sites->toArray())`

Comment: weird I was doing  var sites = "{!! json_encode($sites->toArray()) !!}"; with quotes and it no work, ty.

Comment: @Andrew you can remove the double quote and try again.

Comment: hi @ken. can u hrlp me in that question https://stackoverflow.com/q/75150981/14913109

Answer (score 48):

**Standard PHP objects**

The best way to provide PHP variables to JavaScript is `json_encode`. When using Blade you can do it like following:

```
<script>
    var bool = {!! json_encode($bool) !!};
    var int = {!! json_encode($int) !!};
    /* ... */
    var array = {!! json_encode($array_without_keys) !!};
    var object = {!! json_encode($array_with_keys) !!};
    var object = {!! json_encode($stdClass) !!};
</script>
```

- [Displaying unescaped data - Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data)
- [json_encode - PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

There is also a Blade directive for decoding to `JSON`. I'm not sure since which version of Laravel but in 5.5 it is available. Use it like following:

```
<script>
    var array = @json($array);
</script>
```

- [Blade Templates - Laravel 5.5 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade)

**Jsonable's**

When using Laravel objects e.g. `Collection` or `Model` you should use the `->toJson()` method. All those classes that implements the `\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Jsonable` interface supports this method call. The call returns automatically `JSON`.

```
<script>
    var collection = {!! $collection->toJson() !!};
    var model = {!! $model->toJson() !!};
</script>
```

When using `Model` class you can define the `$hidden` property inside the `class` and those will be filtered in `JSON`. The `$hidden` property, as its name describs, hides sensitive content. So this mechanism is the best for me. Do it like following:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /* ... */

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'ip_address' /* , ... */
    ];

    /* ... */
}
```

And somewhere in your view

```
<script>
    var user = {!! $user->toJson() !!};
</script>
```

- [Serializing to JSON - Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json)

Comment: The best way according with what?

Comment: According to use huge libraries or directly responding it to the client which is an often seen solution.

Comment: Worth noting [not all valid JSON are valid JavaScript (old version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752156/are-all-json-objects-also-valid-javascript-objects), but PHP seems to always escape `"\u2029"` even with `JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS| JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` so this should be safe regardless.

Answer (score 16):

Let's say you have a collection named `$services` that you are passing to the view.

**If you need a JS array with the names**, you can iterate over this as follows:

```
<script>
    const myServices = [];
    @foreach ($services as $service)
        myServices.push('{{ $service->name }}');
    @endforeach
</script>
```

Note: If the string has special characters (like `ó` or HTML code), you can use `{!! $service->name !!}`.

**If you need an array of objects** (with all of the attributes), you can use:

```
<script>
  const myServices = @json($services);
  // ...
</script>
```

Note: This blade directive `@json` is not available for old Laravel versions. You can achieve the same result using `json_encode` as described in other answers.

---

Sometimes you don't need to pass a complete collection to the view, and just an array with 1 attribute. If that's your case, you better use `$services = Service::pluck('name');` in your Controller.

Comment: Why not using `var sampleTags = [{{ $services->implode(',') }}];` or similar?

Comment: As I remember, latest versions of Laravel have also a blade directive that simplifies it like `@json($services)`.

Answer (score 11):

**2022**

Laravel has been [updated](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-json) so this can now be simplified to:

```
<script>const langs = {{ Js::from(Language::all()) }};</script>
```

Or, for any PHP object:

```
<script>const jsObject = {{ Js::from($phpObject) }};</script>
```

This also adds the `JSON_HEX_TAG`s mentioned in [Ken's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201101/11508792) answer.

Comment: Supported in v8 as well https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-json

Answer (score 5):

```
$langs = Language::all()->toArray();
return View::make('NAATIMockTest.Admin.Language.index', [
    'langs' => $langs
]);
```

then in view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var langs = {{json_encode($langs)}};
    console.log(langs);
</script>
```

Its not pretty tho

Comment: thanks for your code but it shows me this problem: FatalErrorException in LanguageController.php line 34:
Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object

Comment: can you post the code on that line and anything relevant to it?

Comment: this error is Undefined variable: langs (View: /home/thienvulai/laravel/sls/resources/views/NAATIMockTest/Admin/Language/create.blade.php). When i tried to use Javascript::put([
   'langs' => $names
   ]);

Comment: my code isnt using the Javascript class. If you just create a test method in your controller with my code only, and then comment everything else in the view except for my code you should see the langs object in the console. You can then use the langs variable in the javascript

Comment: Thanks  Pawel Bieszczad,  The Alpha and everyone who tries to fix my problem. I've just woke up. Yeah i did try your code Pawel Bieszczad but its so me the problems: "uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &". And I'm doing with laravel-5 not laravel-4 so the file filters.php is not exist. So what should i do.

Comment: Do you have any other JavaScript files loaded in that view? Try excluding any other code in the controller, JavaScript and view, just to see if you get the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to put it in a hidden div in php blade

```php
<div hidden id="token">{{$token}}</div>
```

then call it in javascript as a constant to avoid undefined var errors

```js
const token = document.querySelector('div[id=token]').textContent

// console.log(token)
// eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI5MjNlOTcyMi02N2NmLTQ4M2UtYTk4Mi01YmE5YTI0Y2M2MzMiLCJqdGkiOiI2Y2I1ZGRhNzRhZjNhYTkwNzA3ZjMzMDFiYjBiZDUzNTZjNjYxMGUyZWJlNmYzOTI5NzBmMjNjNDdiNjhjY2FiYjI0ZWVmMzYwZmNiZDBmNyIsImlhdCI6IjE2MDgwODMyNTYuNTE2NjE4IiwibmJmIjoiMTYwODA4MzI1Ni41MTY2MjUiLCJleHAiOiIxNjIzODA4MDU2LjMxMTg5NSIsInN1YiI6IjUiLCJzY29wZXMiOlsiYWRtaW4iXX0.GbKZ8CIjt3otzFyE5aZEkNBCtn75ApIfS6QbnD6z0nxDjycknQaQYz2EGems9Z3Qjabe5PA9zL1mVnycCieeQfpLvWL9xDu9hKkIMs006Sznrp8gWy6JK8qX4Xx3GkzWEx8Z7ZZmhsKUgEyRkqnKJ-1BqC2tTiTBqBAO6pK_Pz7H74gV95dsMiys9afPKP5ztW93kwaC-pj4h-vv-GftXXc6XDnUhTppT4qxn1r2Hf7k-NXE_IHq4ZPb20LRXboH0RnbJgq2JA1E3WFX5_a6FeWJvLlLnGGNOT0ocdNZq7nTGWwfocHlv6pH0NFaKa3hLoRh79d5KO_nysPVCDt7jYOMnpiq8ybIbe3oYjlWyk_rdQ9067bnsfxyexQwLC3IJpAH27Az8FQuOQMZg2HJhK8WtWUph5bsYUU0O2uPG8HY9922yTGYwzeMEdAqBss85jdpMNuECtlIFM1Pc4S-0nrCtBE_tNXn8ATDrm6FecdSK8KnnrCOSsZhR04MvTyznqCMAnKtN_vMDpmIAmPd181UanjO_kxR7QIlsEmT_UhM1MBmyfdIEvHkgLgUdUouonjQNvOKwCrrgDkP0hkZQff-iuHPwpL-CUjw7GPa70lp-TIDhfei8T90RkAXte1XKv7ku3sgENHTwPrL9QSrNtdc5MfB9AbUV-tFMJn9T7k
```

Comment: Underrated answer, this is the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

if it's an array you may want to write it like this `JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($months) !!}')`

For anyone else still struggling.

Answer (score 1):

Is very easy, I use this code:

**Controller**:

```
$langs = Language::all()->toArray();
return view('NAATIMockTest.Admin.Language.index', compact('langs'));
```

**View**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var langs = <?php echo json_decode($langs); ?>;
    console.log(langs);
</script>
```

hope it has been helpful, regards!

Answer (score -1):

For me in Laravel v9.2 has this worked.

```
<script> const something_var = <?php echo json_encode($example->something) ?>;</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

It's Simple and It worked for me...

Just pass the PHP variable into single quotes...

```
<script>
    var collection = '{{ $collection }}';
</script>
```

Comment: This won't work if the value has single quotes in it.