# Textarea v-model initial value with VueJS and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, v-model

I want to display the username as the default textarea value for markdown editor using blade syntax.

```
<textarea v-model="message">
      {{ $detailsFromLaravelContoller }}
</textarea>
<div v-html="compiledMarkdown"></div>
```

But I am using v-model component for the textarea which requires to [declare message with an empty value](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties) like this

```
window.onload = function()
{ 
    var editor = new Vue({
    el: '#editor',
    data: {
        message: '',
        compiledMarkdown: marked('', { sanitize: true }), 
    },
    watch: {
        markdown: function () {
          this.compiledMarkdown = marked(this.message, { sanitize: true })
        }
      }, 
      methods: {
        
      }
  })  
}
```

This renders the screen with the **laravel variable's value**. But soon **after the page loads the content disappears** (as I've used window.onload I guess).
Also I'm not using **inline VueJS**.

P.S: I'm new to both VueJS and Laravel and **the source for the markdown** is [here(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/0dzvcf4d/9942/)
**Thank you in advance!!!**

Comment: [even with an empty value](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties)

Comment: Yes. Soon after the page loads the **textarea value disappears**. I was able to notice that the content is being rendered but removed immediately after screen loading by **reloading the page repeatedly**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass a PHP variable value to a separate Javascript file.

Here's how I would do it:

Declare a global variable `detailsFromLaravelContoller` to store $detailsFromLaravelContoller as a string value

```
<script>
    var detailsFromLaravelContoller = @json($detailsFromLaravelContoller);
</script>
<textarea v-model="message">
</textarea>
```

use the global variable in Javascript file

```
data: {
    message: detailsFromLaravelContoller,
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/0dzvcf4d/9954/

Comment: is `'{{ $detailsFromLaravelContoller }}'` the same as `{!! $detailsFromLaravelContoller!!};` ?

Comment: @SebastienD I've changed it to {!! $detailsFromLaravelContoller!!} . I know php but I don't really know laravel. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201101/5599288) use {!! !!}, so I follow it now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: answer updated based on @SebastienD's suggestion. `json_encode` should help you escape the special characters used in markdown.

Comment: That helped to escape the illegal characters. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize the `v-model` in data with your laravel variable.

```
window.onload = function()
{ 
    var editor = new Vue({
    el: '#editor',
    data: {
        message: {!! $detailsFromLaravelContoller !!},
        compiledMarkdown: marked('', { sanitize: true }), 
    },
    watch: {
        markdown: function () {
          this.compiledMarkdown = marked(this.message, { sanitize: true })
        }
      }, 
      methods: {

      }
  })  
}
```

Comment: This one seems a little reliable because VueJS gives me a warning when using script tags in templates. 
I'll try both the answers and mark the one which satisfies my team members.
Thanks for answering.