# Laravel vue textarea content not showing

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have this code:

```
 <textarea id="description" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('description') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="description" rows="3" :maxlength="max" v-model="text" required>{{ $post->description ?? old('description') }}</textarea>
```

When exists: `$post->description` text in textarea not showing. Why? When I remove `v-model="text"` all working..

In App.js:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    max: 137,
    text: '',
    textIm: '',
}
});
```

Comment: is your `text` property  empty string?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yeah... `text: ''`

Comment: i recommend to use axios to get that data

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim create new function for get description of post? This is hard, 1) I need create new component vue 2) I need create function in laravel 3) I need create new route in laravel. This is very hard. In blade I have ready variable for description..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textarea v-model initial value with VueJS and Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767714/textarea-v-model-initial-value-with-vuejs-and-laravel)

Comment: please try this `<textarea :set="txt={{ $post->description ?? old('description') }}; text=txt" ...></textarea>`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim `invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in

    txt=`

Comment: Are you using Laravel mix?

Comment: @RossWilson yes..

Comment: so try this again `<textarea :set="text={{ $post->description ?? old('description') }}" ...></textarea>`, please check this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/v3o1qkvr0y) to learn about `:set`

Comment: "v-model will ignore the initial value, checked or selected attributes found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data as the source of truth." - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: I would suggest making a component instead of using the root instance to store your data so that way you can pass the initial data as a prop.