# Fetching locations from DB into Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to fetch locations from DB table. First using controller to keep data in $var

```
public function index()
{

    $adresArray = DB::table("allestates")->select('id','lat','lng','price')->get()->toArray();

    return view('home', compact('adresArray'));


}
```

and then passing those to the blade

```
    var locations = @json($adresArray)

    function initMap()
    {
        var options =
            {
                zoom : 10,
                center : {lat:34.652500, lng:135.506302}
            }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
            var m = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: {
                    lat: location.lat,
                    lng: location.lng
                }
            });

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: location.price
            });

            m.addListener("click", function() {
                infoWindow.open(map, m);
            });
        });

    }
```

> Undefined variable: location

What am I missing here?

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201101/4084160

Comment: Thank you for advice, i tried but no effects. also updated the code in the code @HenryDev

Answer (score 0):

Use this sintax inside js scripts in blade:

```
var addresses = {!! $location !!};
```

Also, looking at your controller, you are not getting a single object so you have to make an iteration over location array to work with every object inside, you can't just place {!!$location->lng !!} like you are doing...

Comment: But in the end how can I iterate lat and lng in the google map?

Comment: check for this answer please https://stackoverflow.com/a/3059129/5458355

Comment: I updated the code in the question. but still no effects, getting undefined var error.

Comment: in your last update you're passing estatesArray in your compact function but the variable name is $adresArray

Comment: I am sorry for typo, already fix it but result is still same.

Comment: Place debugger; after the declaration of variable locations, debug it and post the content of that variable,

Comment: Maybe is coming null from controller

Comment: it can't be because, I tried to pass data into JS directly {{location->lat}} and use @foreach for itaration. it went well i saw the markers with location in the map. But another problem popped up. That's why i try use this way and trying to pass $php var to JS var

Comment: yes but can you pass me the contents of the var locations, before the function initMap() or its null ? if not, chat me

Comment: I am sorry for the burden. I can't debug it because I am getting undefined error! https://imgur.com/a/LrNoFTJ and don't worry about the $estatesArray it's same in controller too.

Comment: The view to return maybe should be layouts.app, not home.. push your proyect to a github repo ..

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. But it'll take a time pushing the project.