# Laravel error 405(Method Not Allowed) Ajax Posting

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Hello i wnat to send my data with ajax to my controller.

My **CODE**

**AJAX**

```
  $.ajax( {
    type:'POST',
    header:{
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url:"{{route('race.post')}}",
    data:{
      _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
      dataType: 'json', 
      contentType:'application/json', 
    }


})
.done(function() {
    alert('success');
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("error");
});
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 public function Points(Request $request){
    $test = $request->input('data');
    return "$test";
}
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::post('updateC', ['uses' =>'RacesController@Points', 'as' => 'race.post']);
```

**And there are the errors what i get.**

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKgJI.jpg)

[Network-preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvZ8h.jpg)

[Network-Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peBtg.jpg)

Comment: I think You have separate .js file for ajax. that's why your route and csrf_token is not working.

Comment: That's true i have separetad js file for ajax.

Comment: Thats why it is not working. for csrf_token use meta tag. and for url pass url as parameter to javascript onclick, or Onchange function. can i see your .js fiile when the ajax will call..

Comment: try my answer as below. I have changed the code by comparing previous and current question of you.

Answer (score 8):

I just removed the slash at the end of url and it began working...
`/managers/games/id/push/` to:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "/managers/games/id/push",
```

Comment: OMG, this is what was happening to me! I can't believe I have lost 3 hours looking for the error! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a ton Harry, I was searching for a solution for last half an hour. It worked

Comment: This solution possibly works when your server configuration is different than laravel valet config. My endpoint works fine on valet hosted local environment even when there is '/' at the end but on my serverpilot deployment behind cloudflare, it was failing with 405.

Answer (score 1):

add this one in your layout.blade file

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

then use this one in your js code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

i hope this will help!!

Answer (score 1):

First thing is we put two routes in one for displaying view and another for post ajax. So simple add both routes in your route file.

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('ajaxRequest', 'RacesController@Points');

Route::post('ajaxRequest', 'RacesController@Points');
```

Include this meta tag inside your view

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Include javascript code inside your ajax call

```
$.ajaxSetup({

    headers: {

        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working in a JavaScript file and not in a Blade file, the `route()` helper method is not working, and the route 'race.post' isn't parsed to an url.

Try to change the url to this:

```
url: '/updateC'
```

When you want to use the `route()` helper in your JavaScript, you have to add the script to a Blade file, and json_encode the value, you can read more about this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201101/4593376).

Comment: When i used this way `url: '/updateC'` it just say method 405(Method not allowed).

Comment: Try to run `php artisan route:list` and compare the route with the one in your console / network tab. Adapt the route in your ajax call to the one that is shown in your route list.

Comment: It say to use `createPoints` but when i used it the error is 419(Unknown status).

Comment: @Patrik check my answer (comment) from your previous question.

Comment: Nice, that means this issue is resolved. A 419 means the `csrf_token` is wrong. Does this meta tag exist in your blade file: `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`? Try to log if jQuery finds the value of the csrf token.

Answer (score 0):

I have different way to use it: 
AJAX

```
data = {
        selectmanufacturer: selectmanufacturer,
        categories: selectCategory,
        _token: "{{csrf_token()}}",
        productName: productName
      };
     $.ajax({
        url: '{{URL::to('/all-products-data')}}',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
        },
          error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
          }
        });
```

Controller:

```
public function Points(Request $request){
    $test = $request->all();
    return "$test";
}
```

I hope It will be helpful to you

Comment: I tried it and it said that the url wasn found 404(Not found).

Answer (score 0):

The URL you’re posting to doesn’t look right in the console output you posted. In your AJAX code, you have this:

```
url:"{{route('race.post')}}"
```

But that’s just getting interpreted as is, it’s *not* getting interpreted as the value of that route in Laravel.

You’ll need to make sure that your JavaScript code is in a Blade template if you want Blade tags parsed.

Comment: I think he have separte js file thats why csrf_token and url is not working.

Comment: Yes, that’s why I said @Patrik will need to make sure the JavaScript code is in a Blade template.

Answer (score 0):

not type: "POST", method :'POST" try the below code i have modified. ref: [Reference Link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
HTML code

```
<button onClick="onBtnClick()" data-url="{{route('race.post')}}"></button>
```

Updated Code

```
function onBtnClick(){
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");    
    $.ajax( {
        method:'POST',
        header:{
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
        },
        url: url,
        data:{
          _token: token,
          dataType: 'json', 
          contentType:'application/json', 
        }        
    })
    .done(function() {
        alert('success');
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your laravel route is correctly set for this request.
In my case, I had a $.ajax `url: "crop-image-upload"` and a `Route::post('crop-image-upload ', 'CropImageController@uploadCropImage');`
But the request was sent to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/crop-image-upload`
So I had to change my route to `Route::post('/news/crop-image-upload ', 'CropImageController@uploadCropImage');`

So, in your case, try to add a literal url on ajax like this:

```
url:"/races/updateC"
```

and add 'races/' in the route like this:

```
Route::post('/races/updateC', ['uses' =>'RacesController@Points', 'as' => 'race.post']);
```