# Why when I consult the server many times it returns a 405 error Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I am getting error 405 when trying to access a search path. POST method. I send 10 requests 9 processes them correctly and 1 with error or this number is relative.

I don't know if it is a laravel, apache or PHP version configuration? Could you guide me, I can show files that you request. This only happens on my production server.

[image]

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.svg|\.ico|\.json|\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.woff)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|img|fonts|audios|imagenes|svg|storage)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]

</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039998/laravel-error-405method-not-allowed-ajax-posting

Comment: @MohammadAliAkbari Not all the questions that have 403 will be related, in this case the requests are executed, some are rejected,

Answer (score 0):

Probably the programmer set a throttle on that route and after a few requests it's reach it's limitation and return 405