# How to pass a variable ( laravel ) to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

So, I need to pass two variables from laravel ( `$event->latitude` and `$event->longitude` ) to Javascript because I need to use this values for Google Maps.These are 2 values like... latitude : 44.4590762 and longitude : 26.0967384000000.

So, what I had tried to make ...

```
var mylat = {!! json_encode($event->latitude->toArray()) !!};
var mylng = {!! json_encode($event->longitude->toArray()) !!};

or 

var mylat = {!! $event->latitude !!}
var mylng = {!! $event->longitude !!}
```

but without a result.My variables still has no values.

Here is my EventController:

```
$event->longitude = $request['longitude'];
$event->latitude = $request['latitude'];
```

My view:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

My script:

```
<script>
    var mylat = {!! json_encode($event->latitude->toArray()) !!};
    var mylng = {!! json_encode($event->longitude->toArray()) !!};


function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: mylat, lng: mylng},
      zoom: 18
    });
    var input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        marker.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }

        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
        }
        marker.setIcon(({
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
        }));
        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);

        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }

        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        //Location details
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'postal_code'){
                document.getElementById('postal_code').innerHTML = place.address_components[i].long_name;
            }
            if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'country'){
                document.getElementById('country').innerHTML = place.address_components[i].long_name;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = place.formatted_address;
        document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lat();
        document.getElementById('lon').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lng();
        document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.location();
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: "but doesn't working" is no error description. Please read [ask] and edit your question.

Comment: What is the actual generated HTML/JS code?

Comment: It looks as your file is not parsed by PHP as Laravel template at all. Your recent edit ("my script") is what the browser receives?

Comment: According to https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade you should use `@` commands or  plain PHP  to execute expressions. See "Rendering JSON"

Comment: Check this answer, it'll help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074107/laravel-5-passing-variable-to-javascript

Comment: @workservice thank you.I saw that, but I can't figure out how to  implement it to my code. Because here is a variable `$sites = Site::all();`, how should I make with mine? Something like `$latitude = Event::where('latitude','=',$data['event']->latitude)->first`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution was like that:
I have made the variables with php in my view :

```
<?php $latitude =  $event->latitude  ?>
<?php $longitude =  $event->longitude  ?>
```

and here is my variables in script:

```
var mylat = <?= $latitude ?>;
var mylng = <?= $longitude ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Store   `$event` in javascript  variable  use it.

Comment: how to make that?