# How do i pass data from blade to blade file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I try to pass two value from javascript to another blade file after click button to redirect to new window  ...Here is my code

ReportCreate.blade.php js

```
 $("#state").on("change", function() {
            var id = $(this).val();
            console.log(id)
            var cuid = document.getElementById("cu").value;  
            console.log(cuid)

        });

    </script>
```

Click button to open new window which is carry two value from javascript

```
onclick="openNewWindow('{{ route('sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen') }}')"
```

slaCategoryTreeListScreen.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script>
// how do i retrieve two value from another blade file
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You'll need to send those values when making the request. You can do this with query params [passing a second argument](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-route) on the [route()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-route) helper:

```
onclick="openNewWindow('{{ route('sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen', ['id' => 123, 'cuid' => 456]) }}')"
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then, you get those values in your controller to finally return them to the second blade file:

```
# MyCoolController.php

public function toMySecondView(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $cuid = $request->get('cuid');

    return view('my_cool_second_view', ['id' => $id, 'cuid' => $cuid]);
}
```

Just then you'll be able to use them in your second view:

```
# my_cool_second_view.blade.php

<span> ID: { $id } </span>
<span> CUID: { $cuid } </span>
```

Comment: how do i retrieve the id and cuid in javascript method from my second view??? because i want to make ajax from my second view after i get that id and cuid

Comment: Check this SO answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201101/8388597

You can use json_encode inside handlebar brackets to access data in JS passed to Laravel view