# Laravel - assign js variable php value

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, variables

How do i assign a js variable a php value, for example i have this js variable called nr and a php var $nr.

```
@php
    $gal = \App\Gallery::where('id',$wid[1])->first();
    $p = json_decode($gal->photo,true);
    $nr = count($p);
@endphp

 <script>
    var nr={PHP variable here};</script>
```

Comment: Not a big fan of using `@php ... @endphp` in a _view_ file, I'd declare it in the Controller, assign it to the view and use `<script>var nr={{$myVar}}</script>` in the view file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel-5 passing variable to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074107/laravel-5-passing-variable-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try this `var nr= {{!! $nr !!}};`
2. You can change your code a bit and achieve the same result by doing this:

```
@php
    $gal = \App\Gallery::where('id',$wid[1])->first()->photo;
@endphp

<script>
    var gal = @json($gal)
    var nr = gal.length
</script>
```