# How can I let javascript read a laravel asset?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am building a slideshow by having a navbar.js document with:

```
  images[0] = "{{ asset('cover/deanna-j-3GZlhROZIQg-unsplash.jpg')}}";
  images[1] = "{{ asset('cover/kevin-laminto-iRZQjV--Z_4-unsplash.jpg')}}";
  images[2] = "{{ asset('cover/pexels-andrew-neel-2123337.jpg')}}";
  images[3] = "{{ asset('cover/pexels-leah-kelley-952588.jpg')}}";
  images[4] = "{{ asset('cover/pexels-pixabay-460736.jpg')}}";
  images[5] = "{{ asset('cover/pexels-tiff-ng-2711718.jpg')}}";
```

in in the frontend the slideshow is working but javascript doesn't translate asset into: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cover/deanna-j-3GZlhROZIQg-unsplash.jpg which why the pictures are not showing.

How can javascript read a javascript laravel asset?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201101/12733135

Answer (score 0):

you can create a window object for asset url

in main `layout.blade.php`

```php
<script>
    window.asset = "{{ asset('/') }}";
</script>
```

then in `navbar.js`

you can get `asset`

```js
let images = [];

images[0] = window.asset+"cover/deanna-j-3GZlhROZIQg-unsplash.jpg";
images[1] = window.asset+"cover/kevin-laminto-iRZQjV--Z_4-unsplash.jpg";
images[2] = window.asset+"cover/pexels-andrew-neel-2123337.jpg";
images[3] = window.asset+"cover/pexels-leah-kelley-952588.jpg";
images[4] = window.asset+"cover/pexels-pixabay-460736.jpg";
images[5] = window.asset+"cover/pexels-tiff-ng-2711718.jpg";
```

Comment: It is display in the console: http://127.0.0.1:8000/undefinedcover/deanna-j-3GZlhROZIQg-unsplash.jpg 404 (Not Found)           it is displaying undefinedcover instead of cover

Comment: you have to put  `window.asset = "{{ asset('/') }}";` in your main blade file and that file should have this `navbar.js` file and `window.asset` declare this before `navbar.js` so it can be accessed

Answer (score 0):

````
images[1] = 'cover/kevin-laminto-iRZQjV--Z_4-unsplash.jpg';
images[2] = 'cover/pexels-andrew-neel-2123337.jpg';
images[3] = 'cover/pexels-leah-kelley-952588.jpg';
images[4] = 'cover/pexels-pixabay-460736.jpg';
images[5] = 'cover/pexels-tiff-ng-2711718.jpg'; ```
````

Comment: This is the solution