# I want to display my variable which i passed form php to script tag in the laravel blade page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Student Pass/Fail", "Count"],
    ["Pass",{{$pass_data}}],
    ["Fail",{{$fail_data}}], 
]);
```

This is my script code on Laravel blade page and I want to show those variable which I passed from the controller and its showing that **$pass_data is undefined**
I have a array which I want to display on the script tag which for loop but displaying variable like {{$var}} its showing errors .
Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: how you're passing data from the controller? Add your controller codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use PHP data in JS script tags, use the available Blade directive ***@json*** for decoding it to JSON. In your case you can pass those **$pass_data** and **$fail_data** variables as:

```
<script>
  let pass_data = @json($pass_data)
  let fail_data = @json($fail_data)

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Student Pass/Fail", "Count"],
    ["Pass", pass_data],
    ["Fail", fail_data], 
  ]);
</script>
```

You can learn more about it from previously answered post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074107/passing-a-php-variable-to-javascript-in-a-blade-template)

Comment: It is a js error which means that variable is not defined. If the pass_data is correctly passed from the controller, which he has mentioned that he has, he can try using the @json blade directive and give it a go. If that doesn't work, we all here can look it up and guide him.

Comment: @RahulKumawat You're welcome. Please try to add images of errors you're receiving or more information about your questions in future. That helps us in figuring things out and replying to you with a proper solution.

Comment: Okay , for array the process is same ? 
like var st_pass[] = @json($st_pass);  ?
– Jyotishmoy

Comment: `
var one = @json($one);
var two = @json($two);

function drawStacked() {               
                      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                      ['Location', 'Pass'],
                      [one[0],two[0]],
                      [one[1],two[1]],

for (let i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) {
                            [locs[i],st_pass[i],st_fail[i]]
                        }
                      ]);
]}
`those raw statements are working but the loop isnt working

Comment: Check if you're able to console log any of the one[0] or two[0] values first. If the values are present and still it is not working then try defining the array's [one[0],two[0]] and [one[1],two[1] beforehand and use the variables instead. Also check your console if there's any syntax or other issues with the google chart library docs.