# Use variables from Laravel blade in Javascript files

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I have variable `const deleteUrl = "{{ url('ingredients') }}/";` in my `index.blade.php` file.
I want to use it in `index.js`, but in console I have:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: deleteUrl is not defined at index-4b1b8432.js:77:27775

What can I do to fix it?

My code:

`index.blade.php`:

```
<x-app-layout>
{{-- another code --}}
</x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="jsFiles">
    const deleteUrl = "{{ url('ingredients') }}/";
    <script src="{{ asset("js/ingredients/index.js") }}"></script>
</x-slot>
```

`index.js`:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
$(function() {
    console.log(deleteUrl);
};
```

`app.blade.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
        <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js', 'resources/js/ingredients/index.js'])
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
            @include('layouts.navigation')

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            @if (isset($header))
                <header class="bg-white shadow">
                    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                        {{ $header }}
                    </div>
                </header>
            @endif

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <main>
                {{ $slot }}
            </main>
        </div>
        <!-- JS Files -->
        {{ $jsFiles ?? '' }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Only answer from @miken23 helps.

```
<input type="hidden" id="deleteUrl" value="{{url('ingredients')}}/"/>
```

I saw, when I put

```
<script>
    const deleteUrl = "{{ url('ingredients') }}/";
</script>
```

In my app.blade.php before @vite it works to.

```
<!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        const deleteUrl = "{{ url('ingredients') }}/";
    </script>
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js', 'resources/js/ingredients/index.js'])
```

Comment: Better solution: Use Vue or Svelte as a front-end and connect this to Laravel via Inertia.

Comment: Try `window.deleteUrl = ...` instead. Access using `window.` as well. At least this way the value will exist no matter what script you use it from. Implementing a proper API might be even more useful so the deleteUrl doesn't get cached.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a PHP variable to JavaScript in a Blade template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074107/passing-a-php-variable-to-javascript-in-a-blade-template)

Comment: @miken32 I saw it. I try to use it, but it doesn't help (or I did something wrong)

Comment: `<input type="hidden" id="deleteUrl" value="{{url('ingredients')}}" />` and then in your script `let deleteUrl = $("#deleteUrl").val();`

Comment: put `const deleteUrl = "{{ url('ingredients') }}/";` inside a script tag so that `js/ingredients/index.js` can detect `deleteUrl`

Answer (score 1):

I think `window` global object would work in this case, i had a similar requirement in the past and i have solved it using the same. For e.g in your `index.blade.php` file assign php variable to `window` object like below

```
@php
    $foo = 'Hello, World!';
@endphp

<script>
    window.foo = "{{ $foo }}";
    
</script>
```

and then in your `index.js` file you can retrieve it from `window` global object like below

```
console.log(window.foo); // Hello, World!
```

PS: Dont forget to add `defer` attribute while including this script any where because `defer` loads the script asynchronously after the HTML content has been parsed so that you can access your variable in window object easily.

Comment: I did it and now when I use `console.log(window.foo);` in console I have `undefined`

Comment: Have you used  defer attribute while including script> like this `<script src="{{ asset('js/index.js') }}" defer></script>`

Comment: Yes I tried to use defer

Answer (score 0):

Change the code from

```
const deleteUrl = "{{ url('ingredients') }}/";
<script src="{{ asset("js/ingredients/index.js") }}"></script>
```

to

```
<script> const deleteUrl = "{{ url('ingredients') }}/"; </script>
<script src="{{ asset("js/ingredients/index.js") }}"></script>
```

What this does is assign variable `deleteUrl` inside JS and use that same variable to all JS files **after** declaration.

[More explanation from other stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3244411)

Answer (score 0):

You can use alpine.js which is used with laravel 10 starter kits.
It works almost like when you use Vue.js .
It's very simple to be learnt and very powerful to use JS with blade as if you are using JS framework.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35674683)